# Android: Handler.post() equivalent in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-handler

In Android, we have `Handler.post()` method which can run after every fixed time interval like this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
  // ... this runs after every second 
  handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // makes run() run after every 1000 ms
  }
}
```

Do we have anything similar in Dart or Flutter?

PS: The similar of `Handler.postDelayed()` is `Future.delayed()`. I am asking for `Handler.post()`

Comment: you want execute some task after delay, right ??

Comment: No, for that we have `Future.delayed()`. Please read my question again.

Comment: yes i read you need timer which work periodically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that. `Timer.periodic()` is the one I should be using.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(microseconds: 1000), (_) {
   // Runs after every 1000ms
});
```

Comment: This should be equivalent to TimerTask I believe